# Is there a way to nest dependent comboboxes on userforms?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set multiple dependent combo boxes up in a user form. For example, the user will select a choice in the first combobox. Depending on their choice, the 2nd combobox is loaded with appropriate choices. From there, I have one selection that leads to a third combobox while the rest finish with the 2nd box. Is there a way to make that happen? I can make the first part work, but not the 2nd.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Label10.Visible = False
ComboBox3.Visible = False

With RegionBox
    .AddItem "1"
    .AddItem "2"
    .AddItem "3"
End With
End Sub
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim index As Integer, index2 As Integer

index = ComboBox1.ListIndex
index2 = ComboBox2.ListIndex

BuildingBox.Clear

Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        With BuildingBox
            .AddItem "1"
            .AddItem "2"
            .AddItem "3"
        End With
            Select Case index2 'This select case is where doesn't work
                Case 0
                    With HQBox
                        .Visible = True
                        .AddItem "1"
                        .AddItem "2"
                        .AddItem "3"
                    End With
                    Label10.Visible = True
            End Select 
    Case Is = 1
        With BuildingBox
            .AddItem "1"
            .AddItem "2"
            .AddItem "3"
        End With
    Case Is = 2
        With BuildingBox
            .AddItem "1"
            .AddItem "2"
            .AddItem "3"
        End With
End Select

End Sub
```

I am hoping to have the 3rd box hidden unless the choice in combobox 2 (first one) is selected, triggering it to be shown. So far, the selections in combobox2 are added in correctly based on the selection of combobox1, but I can't get combobox3 to be filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part responsible for creating third combobox should be in ComboBox2_Change() function.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Label10.Visible = False
ComboBox3.Visible = False

With RegionBox
    .AddItem "1"
    .AddItem "2"
    .AddItem "3"
End With
End Sub
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim index As Integer

index = ComboBox1.ListIndex

BuildingBox.Clear

Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        With BuildingBox
            .AddItem "1"
            .AddItem "2"
            .AddItem "3"
        End With
    Case Is = 1
        With BuildingBox
            .AddItem "1"
            .AddItem "2"
            .AddItem "3"
        End With
    Case Is = 2
        With BuildingBox
            .AddItem "1"
            .AddItem "2"
            .AddItem "3"
        End With
End Select

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim index2 As Integer

index2 = ComboBox2.ListIndex

HQBox.Clear
HQBox.Visible = False
Label10.Visible = False

Select Case index2
    Case Is = 0
        With HQBox
            .Visible = True
            .AddItem "1"
            .AddItem "2"
            .AddItem "3"
        End With
        Label10.Visible = True
End Select

End Sub
```